# discrepancy in latency between rails request logs and chrome network tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, ajax, performance, rest

A Rails API call shows a duration of 894m in the request logs locally, where the render looks like this: `render status: :ok, json: { ... }`

```
:status => 200,
:duration => 894.95,
:view => 7.87,
```

I'm rendering an array of objects (not `ActiveRecord`), but I didn't override `as_json` with crazy implementations or anything.

This is a SPA, an Angular frontend. When I open the network tab in Chrome console for the same API call, it shows that it's been waiting for 3s before the first byte:
[image: Chrome Console]

I'm trying to speed up a page in my app and this API call is a big one. How can I figure what what is causing this discrepancy?

Comment: How are you calculating the `894.95 ms` duration? Is it the rails instrumentation or you calculated it on your own?

Comment: @dravit that is rails instrumentation that is available by default.

Comment: facing same issue, anything you figured out?